# React Component changing from function to class - State and state hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a question, because i can't find answer anywhere.
The problem is: what is the initial value of the following hook:
"Function" Example:

```
function Example() {
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState({});

  return (
     ...
  );
}
```

And here i'm writing this function "Example" as class, but i don't know how to initialize state
(is it empty string or empty list or 0 value?)

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
             settings: <-- and what here?
        };
    }
```

Comment: `{}`? That's the value you give to the hook. Could you not `console.log(settings)` in the former and find out?

Comment: The initial state is an empty object. `this.state = {settings: {}}` is equivalent.

Comment: const [settings, setSettings] = useState({}); is equivalent to this.state = {settings: {}};

Comment: Ohhhh, omg, i was looking for this for an hour ! thanks guys

Comment: I'm so sorry for the obvious... :/

Comment: @emsiiggy No problem. I opted to write an answer for future passerbys. If you find it's accurate, feel free to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` is passed the initial value as its only param - in your case `{}`.

You can accomplish the same in your second code snippet like so:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
             settings: {}
        };
    }
}
```

#### Further reading:

- [The React docs have an example almost identical to yours.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#equivalent-class-example)
- [`useState` source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L77)